Project building is failing with ruby -e "require 'xcodeproj'
I tried running flutterfire configure from my terminal and receive  an xcodeproj error :
% export PATH="/usr/local/opt/ruby/bin:$PATH"
% flutterfire configure
i Found 2 Firebase projects.                                                                                                                     
✔ Select a Firebase project to configure your Flutter application with · newproject-b732b (newproject)                                           
✔ Which platforms should your configuration support (use arrow keys & space to select)? · android, ios                                           
i Firebase android app com.example.globalchat registered.                                                                                        
i Firebase ios app com.example.globalchat registered.

Exception: <internal:/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/3.3.2/lib/ruby/3.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:136:in `require': cannot load such file -- xcodeproj (LoadError)
        from <internal:/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/3.3.2/lib/ruby/3.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:136:in `require'
        from -e:1:in `<main>'

What should I do?

tried running
brew install ruby

and it's still giving me error.
